# AVPlayer doesn't play https url

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer, ios10

I am using local server to get url for AVPlayer. Server doesn't have any domain.
like https://some_ip_addr:port/project/SampleVideo.mp4
AVPlayer doesn't play https url but it play http url.
Server doesn't have any domain.
Does AVPlayer needs some extra coding to play https request? am I missing something?

```
 player = AVPlayer(url: url)
 let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
 playerViewController.player = player
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerDidReachEndNotificationHandler:")), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player!.currentItem)
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true)
{
     playerViewController.player!.play()
}
```

Comment: AVPlayer works with https url. You should put some code if you want help.

Comment: I have added my code.The url is from local server

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I don't see any error. Video doesn't play

Comment: @iBeginner Did you solve this issue.I am also having same problem.